# Powershell (PS2) logging Remove-Item

Tags: powershell

I'm fairly new to Powershell but manged so far to pull together a script that deletes files older than a defined Created Date and excluding certain file types. However, I'm struggling to incorporate both verbose and file logging output. I've tried various methods I've found online and I think Out-File is the most appropriate however I simply can't make it work. Hoping someone can help!

```
    Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
    # $Logfile = "C:\Temp\Log.log"

    function Remove-Files([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})][string] $Path, [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][DateTime] $DateTime, [switch] $WhatIf)

    {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $DateTime -and ($_.Name -notlike "*.txt"-and $_.Name -notlike "*.log")} |
        # Out-File -filepath $logfile -append 
        ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force -WhatIf:$WhatIf}
    }

    Remove-Files -Path "C:\Temp" -DateTime ((Get-Date).AddDays(-10)) # -whatif
```

Comment: The `Tee-Object` cmdlet redirects output in two directions. It stores the output in a file or variable and also sends it down the pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not sending any content to the log file.

Uncomment the `$logfile` declaration, and use this for instance:

```
ForEach-Object {
    Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force -WhatIf:$WhatIf
    "Removed $($_.FullName)" | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is just `Tee-Object` the files before you remove them. Like, literally *just* replace your `Out-File` with `Tee-Object`:

```
function Remove-Files {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [string]$Path,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [DateTime]$DateTime,

        # Personally, I would pass the log file as a parameter
        # [string]$LogFile,

        [switch]$WhatIf
    )

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force | 
        Where-Object { 
            !$_.PSIsContainer -and 
            $_.CreationTime -lt $DateTime -and 
            ($_.lName -notlike "*.txt" -and $_.Name -notlike "*.log")
        } |
        Tee-Object -Filepath $LogFile -Append |
        Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf:$WhatIf
}


Remove-Files -Path "C:\Temp" -Log "C:\Temp\Rm.log" -DateTime ((Get-Date).AddDays(-10))
```

The only problem is that:

1. The output in the log would be formatted the same as if you output to the console, so it's not quite what you'd normally log ...
2. The log will be the same whether you remove or not (i.e.: `-Whatif` makes it not delete, but doesn't stop the log)

Comment: Feels more appropriate :) (your solution, I mean)

Comment: Thanks for the help! So I wasn't able to get Tee-Object working as it didn't like the -Append switch. I did however use your guidance and with a bit more reading got it working (albeit not very elegantly) by using separate commands. My coding is eye-wateringly bad (sorry I'm still learning) but I've added it as an answer below to demonstrate what I've done.

Comment: Yeah, the `-Append` switch was introduced in PowerShell 3.0 -- for what it's worth, if you're using an older version than that, you should really upgrade ;-)

Comment: Ok.. further to this I couldn't get the Out-File & Write-Host to play nicely together so upgraded to PowerShell 3 like you suggested and used Tee-Object -Append. Only issue is as you say with the -Whatif but that's a problem for another day:) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my updated code to get the logging working..

```
    function Remove-FilesCreatedBeforeDate([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})][string] $Path, [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][DateTime] $DateTime, [string]$LogFile = "C:\Temp\Log.log", [switch] $WhatIf)
    {
        "LOG START $(Get-Date –f "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")" | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append 
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $DateTime -and ($_.Name -notlike "*.txt"-and $_.Name -notlike "*.log")} | 
        ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force -WhatIf:$WhatIf 
        "$(Get-Date –f o) Removed $($_.FullName)" | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append | Write-host "Removed $($_.FullName)"}
        "LOG END $(Get-Date –f "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")" | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append 
    }

    Remove-FilesCreatedBeforeDate -Path "C:\Temp" -DateTime ((Get-Date).AddDays(-0))
```

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I have created a [`Log-Entry` framework](https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry) where you can do inline logging like:

`Remove-Item -Path (Log "Removing:" $_.FullName ?) -Force -WhatIf:$WhatIf`